# Can I store Map in sharedpreferences in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to store List data locally somewhere if user goes back from a screen and later access that List if User later redirects to that page. Could anyone help me with that? Thank you

Comment: If you only need to save data across screens, you shouldn't use SharedPreferences and have a look around State management. Here are some options: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: I need to access the saved data even if the app is killed. Could you give some advice??

Comment: You should encode your map as a JSON String when you store the map, and then parse it back into a Map when you want to use it in your app

Answer (score 0):

Using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) you can only store int, double, bool, String and List.